# Replace column by another table sql

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

Using SQL Server 2014, how can I replace the values in a table with values from another table (need coding please).

I have two tables:

1. Coo data table 800 records (has misspelled countries names or additional information)

   ```
   id   response
   --------------------------
   1    Saudi
   2    Honderas born 1992
   3    Argentina%
   4    Ecuadar
   ```
2. Countries table 56 records (correct countries names)

   ```
   Country
   ----------------------
   Saudi Arabia
   Honduras
   Argentina
   Ecuador
   ```

So I tried to use just the first 4 characters

```
  SELECT LEFT(country, 4) AS Short4 
  FROM Countries;
```

Output:

```
Short4
--------
saud
Hond
arge
Ecua
```

so what I would like is
if any value in 'response column' contains 'short4 column' then replace it with value from 'country column'

Desired table: in response column should be just include the correct countries name without any additional values

```
id    response
------------------
 1    Saudi Arabia
 2    Honduras
 3    Argentina
 4    Ecuador
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, wmb8084.  It will be useful for answers to know what you have attempted so far, and how if had not met your needs.  Perhaps edit your questions to include some sample SQL code and the difference between the results you achieved and the results that you desire.

Answer (score 0):

This is rather strange.  I think you are looking fro:

```
select c.*, co.country
from coo c left join
     countries co
     on c.response like '%' + left(co.country, 4) + '%';
```

Obviously there are places where this will not work -- say "USA" in the response where the country name is "United States of America".

Comment: Thank you so much yes, you are right.  this coding works for all it will not work for united states and united Arab emirates. So, is there a spesicfc code for that

Comment: Thank you so much @Gordon Linoff . yes, you are right.  this coding works for all countries except  united states and united Arab emirates. So, is there a specific code for that. for united state I have values 'u.s' , 'u.s.a', 'usa', and 'u.s.' . for United Arab emirates,  UAE. what I would like to USA and UAE as correct format.

Answer (score 0):

The following query should match the tables on your 4 characters and update the response field in the Coo table if they match.

```
UPDATE Coo
   SET Response = c.Country
  FROM Coo x
  JOIN Countries c ON x.Response LIKE '%'+LEFT(c.Country,4)+'%'
```

Comment: I noticed you wanted any match, and not just a beginning match so changed the join to be a LIKE